# Android - linking 2 pictures

Tags: android, image, connect

I have 1 problem. I want to link 2 pictures.
Example:I link picture A with picture B. And when i open picture A and i hold my finger on screen for x second, picture B appears.
How can I do that.
I want to link photos in default gallery. And linking via imageview will need to be in my app ( I open 2 pictures in my app and then link them), but I don't want that. I want like this:
My app will be camera(that I created) and then I take pictures and  ( in backround) my app link 2 pictures and put them in default gallery. And then when someone open first picture(picture A) and hold his finger x seconds, second picture(picture B) appear.
Thanks

Comment: Take an `ImageView` and listen to its long press event and change the source of the `ImageView` inside event fired block

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Put another imageview on that imageview and set your picture2 in that view.

when you long press first imageview make it's visibility gone and visible another imageview.